# Spock custom reporting

Tags: junit, spock

In my Spock Tests, I have my own customer annotations that tell you more about the requirement driving the test spec.

Examples:

```
@AC(story="Some story", project="Some project", ac="1.b")
```

Is it possible to pull these out into the JUnit report?

Thanks

Comment: What are you looking for exactly? It would be quite easy to just print this to standard out.

Comment: In the JUnit reports to have an additional report which will detail the ACs covered in tabular format.  So if it could parse the annotation and output in CSV format followed by if the test passed / failed.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to take a look at https://github.com/renatoathaydes/spock-reports and see if you can customize it to your requirements.